# inter thread comunication using ZeroMQ messages

Tags: c, zeromq

I am trying to use `zeroMQ` as a way to implement a messaging system between multiple threads. I tried the code below but it doesn't work; in the specific the call to `zmq_recv` in each thread doesn't wait/block for any message to be executed.

Can you help me with this piece of code?

I am using Linux OS and gcc

Best Regards

AFG

```
    static void *
    worker_routine (void *context) {
        // Socket to talk to dispatcher
        void *receiver = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
        zmq_connect (receiver, "inproc://workers");
        while (1) {

            zmq_msg_t request;
            zmq_msg_init( &request );
            zmq_recv( receiver, &request, 0 );
            printf ("Received request\n");
            // Do some 'work'
            usleep (1000);
            // Send reply back to client
            zmq_send (receiver, &request, 0);
        }
        zmq_close (receiver);
        return NULL;
    }

    int main (void) {

    void *context = zmq_init (1);
    void *clients = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    zmq_bind (clients, "inproc://workers");

    int thread_nbr;
    for (thread_nbr = 0; thread_nbr < 5; thread_nbr++) {
        pthread_t worker;
        pthread_create (&worker, NULL, worker_routine, context);
    }

    zmq_close (clients);
    zmq_term (context);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I was reading again the guide to ZeroMQ. Does anyone know if I have to  create a zmq_device like QUEUE for my purposes? I also noticed that there are sample using "ipc" as protocol..I always assumed that for MT I MUST use "inproc"..anyone knows if this can have an impact?

Answer (score 6):

Both sockets are REP. What you want is REQ + REP.

Answer (score 3):

You're shutting down the socket and ZeroMQ right after you're creating the threads. They probably don't have time to reach a blocking state, and if they did, they would fail as soon as you destroy the zmq context. From the [zmq_term man page](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1-1%3azmq-term):

> Context termination is performed in the following steps:
>
> Any blocking operations currently in progress on sockets open within context shall **return immediately** with an error code of ETERM.

Comment: I might probably need to add also try adding a bit of "sleep"; anyway still I don't know if the behavior I am expected is fulfilled with that setup..see my comments below the questions. PS. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as @sustrik noted you need to use `REQ` and `REP`, both the main thread and the worker threads cannot be `REP`.

Secondly, you need to provide some sort of blocking loop in your main thread:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *context = zmq_init (1);
    void *clients = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP); // use ZMQ_REQ on the clients
    zmq_bind (clients, "inproc://workers");

    int thread_nbr;
    for (thread_nbr = 0; thread_nbr < 5; thread_nbr++) {
        pthread_t worker;
        pthread_create (&worker, NULL, worker_routine, context);
    }

    while (TRUE)
    {
        // worker thread connected asking for work
        zmq_msg_t request;
        zmq_msg_init (&request);
        zmq_recv (clients, &request, 0);
        zmq_msg_close (&request);

        // do whatever you need to do with the clients' request here

        // send work to clients
        zmq_msg_t reply;
        zmq_msg_init_data (&reply, "Reply", 5, NULL, NULL);
        zmq_send (clients, &reply, 0);
        zmq_msg_close (&reply);
    }

    zmq_close (clients);
    zmq_term (context);
    return 0;
}
```