# How to efficiently pass an argument, just very occasionally met, to a child thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq, atomic, setsockopt

I'd like to pass a string argument to a child thread ( that is continuously reading a socket ) and call a `setsockopt()` with that argument on that socket.

I'm using ZeroMQ sockets, so calling `setsockopt()` is [**not** threadsafe](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-setsockopt) here,  I'd call the `setsockopt()` from the child thread ( as was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841896/0mq-how-to-use-zeromq-in-a-threadsafe-manner/5842249#5842249) ). An argument update would occur probably only once in billions of read cycles, and it feels a bit wrong to add an `if`-structure to the child's every cycle like this:

```
bool new_arg_available;
std::string new_arg;

while(1){
    sub_socket->recv(data);   // . . . . . . a blocking method call
    printData(data)

    ...                       // . . . . . . data can set new_arg_available

    if (new_arg_available){   // . . . . . . synchronization goes here
        sub_socket->setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, new_arg, ... );
        new_arg_available = false;
    }
}
```

For me, the most straightforward would probably be either:

1. Add a mutex to the global namespace, lock it when a `new_arg` available in the parent thread, and unlock it from the child thread.
2. use a `std::atomic<bool>` and use it the same way as in 1.

However, what I would like to achieve somehow is to make the child interruptible, so that I could eliminate the `if`-structure from the end of the `while(){...}` block. I wouldn't mind the penalty of a context switch, because this event would be so seldom.

I'm relatively new to C++, and I would like to learn about best practices here, how to achieve this in an efficient way. I would like to solve it without using Boost, the only examples I could find to achieve interruptible threads were using Boost.

Comment: When a resource is shared among threads you need mutexes. One in the "write" operation, and other in the "read" operation. Unlock each mutext as soon as the operation is done.

Comment: I am really curious about an answer here too,  I cannot think of a way that doesn't poll a boolean in modern c++.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the additional `if`. You could even use some compiler specific construct to specify that the branch is `unlikely`. Another solution would be to have a dedicated socket to pass `new_arg` over. In that case, instead of `sub_socket->recv()` you'd use a `poller` to poll both `sub_socket` and your `new_param_receiver_socket`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Welcome to the land of Zen-of-Zero

The primary remark on the ZeroMQ evangelisation is, that the ZeroMQ authors have advocated since ever to **avoid any sort of sharing** - Zero-sharing.

Given you already have instantiated the ZeroMQ infrastructure, better use an inter-thread **`PUSH/PULL`** over the IO-thread-less **`inproc://`** transport-class and forget about any tricky (b-)locking.

The one side ( the Injector ) just **`aPushCHANNEL.send( new_arg );`**
and the other ( the Implementor ) just either `aPullCHANNEL.recv()`-s as needed / when needed, or may use smarter means of `aPullCHANNEL.poll()`-testing, again best if using the Zero-wait form of the polling-test `if aPullCHANNEL.poll( 0 ){...}else{...}`

And your [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) architecture becomes a fully decomposed, multi-agent role-based clean and smart, without having any dirty deadlocks ( so best forget `REQ/REP` since beginning ), without any hard to trace/debug conceptual flaws and all errors get detected where applicable and where a local responsibility makes sense to map the root-cause of any such error for an on-the-fly due error-handling.

---

**NB:** Yes, ZeroMQ has been since ever designed without a need for a  thread-safeness, as there was nothing left to be shared ( Zero-sharing ). Some recent efforts in API v4.1+ started to decline from this Zen-of-Zero, so one may read about some aspects of thread-safeness, yet as noted above and as present on almost every page of the fabulous Pieter HINTJENS' ZeroMQ bible-book - "**Code Connected, Volume 1**" - best share nothing.

The ZeroMQ design is fully asynchronous and requires no care for locking, mutex-gymnastics and other forms of extrinsically introduced elements in an otherwise clean and smart multi-agent async signalling / messaging based [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) architecture. You will fall in love with it, so keep trying and read the book. It will be hard, yet it will pay a lot for those, who will carry on and find the beauty of ZeroMQ Zen-of-Zero.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that the more complex a zmq design gets with more sockets, the more complicated it becomes to handle them in separate threads, now I can see I'm better off with poll. In the design above I can easily create a "message deadlock" by unsubscribing from all the messages and then get stuck in the blocking recv() in that thread.